# Sync variables / Create an event listener for variables change value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have 2 variables:

```
var connection1, connection2;
connection1 = connection2 = false;
```

And I have 2 different functions that connect to a remote node and change each variable to `true` upon connection:

```
node1.on('open', function () {
    connection1 = true; 
});
node2.on('open', function () {
    connection2 = true; 
});
```

I want a function to run only after both connections are made, without checking the other variable inside each `on` function.

How can I create an event listener that will trigger only when both values are set to `true` **without** using `setInterval` ?

Comment: Since you already have callback functions when each connection is made can't you just ask there if the other one is also connected and then run the code?

Comment: @PredatorIWD No, I simplified the code alot, but it's very complex and I can't do it inside each `on` function. I need something external to them.

Comment: Have you considered js promises? I've created simple [codepen](https://codepen.io/fen1x/pen/yzBLwY?editors=0010) to show how it can be implemented.

Comment: @fen1x Thanks for your example but that is how I implemented it myself. as you can see in the question I dont want to use setTimout since it causes issues in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promise is there to save the day.

```
// Promise.all will fulfill when all promises are resolved or one is rejected
Promise.all(
    [
        new Promise(
            function(resolve, reject)
            {
                node1.on("open", resolve);
            }
        ),
        new Promise(
            function(resolve, reject)
            {
                node2.on("open", resolve);
            }
        )
    ]
)
.then(
    function()
    {
        console.log("Connections 1 & 2 opened");
    }
)
.catch(
    function(error)
    {
        console.log("Error:", error);
    }
);
```